# SQL Server for delete trigger to delete records in other table with procedure

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursors

I've got a table like `table1` (`table1_id, col1, some_ID`) and another `table2` (`table2_id, col1, table1_id`)

I have a procedure

```
PROC deleteTable2(@id int)
AS
BEGIN 
    DELETE table2 
    WHERE table1_id = @id
END
```

I'm trying to create a trigger for delete for `table1` table, so when I'm trying to delete from `table1`, the trigger will delete all records in `table2`.

I wrote the trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTable1 on table1
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @id int = 0

    SELECT @id = del.table1_ID from deleted as del

    EXECUTE dbo.deleteTable2 @id
```

It works if there is only one record for `some_ID`, but if there are more records, it doesn't work. For example:

```
delete table1 
where some_ID='some value'
```

This SQL query will delete all records in table1 and only first in table2.

It makes sense, so I made a trigger with CURSOR, something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTable1 ON table1
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int = 0, @CURSOR cursor

    SET @CURSOR = CURSOR scroll FOR 
       SELECT deleted.table1_id 
       FROM deleted

    OPEN @CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR into @id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
          EXECUTE dbo.deleteTable2 @id
          FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR into @id
    END
    CLOSE @CURSOR
END
```

But it doesn't work at all... Maybe I just missed something or I don't get some nuances. Thank you.

UPDATE

In fact, This 2 tables are in one db, but I've got 3rd table `table3 (table3_id, col1, table2_id)`. And this `table3` is in other db, and they connected by linked server. So when I call stored procedure as I'm trying, this stored procedure calls stored procedure (with  cursor) to delete records in `table3`. That the exact reason why I'm trying to use stored procedure to delete records in table2.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** .... a trigger should be **fast, small and nimble** - everything a **cursor** definitely is NOT!! Please don't kill your system by using a **CURSOR** (of all things) inside a trigger! That's just awful...... use a **set-based** approach shown by @M.Ali in his response - **always**. Cursors inside a triggers is the **worst nightmare** for any SQL Server database! Never ever under any circumstances do that!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using all these unnecessary cursors and stored procedure. Simply follow a set based approach and do the following inside your trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTable1 on table1
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

Delete FROM Table2 
WHERE Exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted del
              WHERE del.table1_ID = table2.Table1_ID)             

END
```

**UPDATE**

Since you have mentioned you would like to delete records from a third table too which is some where on a linked server.

I would suggest you to use the same approach and just add another delete statement in inside the procedure for that third table on the linked server.

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTable1 on table1
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

Delete FROM Table2 
WHERE Exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted del
              WHERE del.table1_ID = table2.Table1_ID)             

DELETE FROM t3
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DBName].[SchemaName].Table3 t3 
WHERE Exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted del
              WHERE del.table1_ID = t3.Table1_ID)             


END
```

Comment: table3 is connected with table2, not table1. Moreover, I'm pretty sure that the trigger won't work, because of a "Transaction context in use by another session" issue. Because we can't delete from other db like that in MS Sql.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTable1 on table1
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table1_id IN (SELECT table1_id FROM deleted)
END
```